# How can I open multi-page Fireworks files?

Tags: software-recommendation, adobe-fireworks

I no longer have Fireworks, but I still have a number of old fireworks files with multiple pages. It appears that I can only access the first page in Photoshop. Does anyone know how I can access additional pages in these files for editing in Photoshop?

Comment: Sad to say, but I'd wager you need Fireworks to resave them as separate files.

Comment: Get Adobe CS3 installation disks. Then you have Fireworks until the trial expires. You need a fresh machine that carries no traces of preinstalled CS3. And an old OS, too. I have no idea which modern Windows versions take it. Win7 is ok. Actually CS3...CS6 all had Fireworks. Before them it was Macromedia Fireworks.

Comment: If you have the whole Creative cloud package then it also includes fireworks. What package or software do you have?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using an "in between" file format as a stepping stone? If this tool still works as advertised, this might help you solve the problem by converting to a PDF, which is easier to import into photoshop etc: http://www.novapdf.com/kb/convert-images-created-with-adobe-fireworks-to-pdf-385.html

Comment: This still requires Fireworks to work, which OP doesn't have anymore...

Comment: Whoops, so it does. I misread. Curses